# Creating an Installer -

Tags: java, installation

Recently I've found the need to create an installer using Java. I need to create a copy of an existing Jar File and add files to it. From what I've gathered, these are the steps I need to do:

1. Extract the contents of a Jar File to a folder.
2. Add my own files to the folder.
3. Turn the folder into a ZIP file.
4. Turn the ZIP to a Jar file.

I've tried to do this but the ZIP file is corrupt when I attempt to do it, other methods I have tried end up making two copies of the files each installation which is obviously inefficient if I want other people to use it.

I would just like some help on how I would accomplish this successfully and what the best way to go about doing it is.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need a script, or an installer? The process you are describing does not sound like an installer to me. Also, you should not 'turn the zip into a jar file'. There is a tool for creating a jar file from a directory, it's called `jar`.

Comment: It's an installer, with a GUI and everything. It's supposed to install files into something that already exists. And I'll take a look at the jar thing right now. I've already got the GUI and everything it's literally just the installation "script" that needs doing.

Comment: @NickL I've tried to use JarFile and I get a "File not found exception (access is denied)".